# Ruby On Rails - what's the best way to find an object with most (has-many) associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, has-many

I have a variable (`@cars`) containing data from the database and from here, I need to generate an XLS document.

Because of some specifics of the XLS document, I need to know in advance the length of some associations (model `Car` has a `has_many` association for the model `PreviousOwner`) - particularly, I need to know how many previous owners each car had and I need to capture the highest number of previous owners of all cars.

One way of finding that is adding `counter_cache` to the `Car` model structure, is there any other way to deal with this situation? I have `@cars` variable and from there I need to find the car with the most previous owners.

Comment: If you need the number of associated records on a regular base then `counter_cache` is the way to go. All other methods would need to recalculate the number each time you read them what makes all other methods slower.

Answer (score 2):

One of the ways of dealing with it is by joining and selecting a count:

```
Car.left_joins(:previous_owners)
   .select(
     'cars.*', 
     'COUNT(previous_owners.*) AS previous_owners_count'
   )
   .group(:id)
   .order(previous_owners_count: :desc)
```

Advantages when compared to a counter cache:

- No additional update queries when inserting associated records.
- More accurate if the count is critical and you have a lot of write activity.

Disadvantages:

- Count is calculated for every query which is less efficient when reading.
- It gets in the way of eager loading the records.
- More code complexity vs a simple model callback.